# AsynkTask Android ошибка An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

В приложении необходимо использовать API Яндекс Словаря. Написал метод, для получения перевода. На Java он работает, начал переносить в Android и столкнулся с ошибкой.

```
Process: com.example.admin.translator, PID: 10933
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.getTranslations(MainActivity.java:352)
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:38)
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:490)
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:479)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.getTranslations(MainActivity.java:352) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:38) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:490) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:479) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306) 
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.getTranslations(MainActivity.java:352) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:38) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:490) 
        at com.example.admin.translator.MainActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:479) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Описание самого класса:

```
class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                text = etInputWords.getText().toString();
                getTranslations(text, langEnRu);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Проверьте подключение к интернету!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Проверьте подключение к интернету!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (!transcription.equals("")){
                tvOunputTranlsation.setText(transcription + "\n" + translations);
            }
            else {
                tvOunputTranlsation.setText(translations);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вызываю его в методе onClick:

```
case R.id.btn_translate: {
                mPos = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EnglishWords WHERE word=\"" + etInputWords.getText()+ "\"", null);
                if (mPos.moveToFirst())
                    tvOunputTranlsation.setText(mPos.getString(3 ) + "\n" +mPos.getString(2));
                else {
                    text = etInputWords.getText().toString();
                    AsyncRequest ar = new AsyncRequest();
                    ar.execute();
                }
                break;
            }
```

Кусок метода getTranslations:

```
private void getTranslations(String text, String langTranslate) throws IOException, JSONException {
        Document docc1 = null;
        String  body, answer;
        String key = "значение";

        docc1 = Jsoup.connect("https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key="+ key + "&lang=" + langTranslate + "&text="+text + "&POS_FILTER=0x0008").ignoreContentType(true).get();
        body = docc1.body().html();
        JSONArray yandexAnswer = new JSONObject(body).getJSONArray("def");
выборка нужных значений
}
```

Ругается почему-то на строку метода getTranslations

```
docc1 = Jsoup.connect("https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key="+ key + "&lang=" + langTranslate + "&text="+text + "&POS_FILTER=0x0008").ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

Comment: `Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`

Comment: а как это можно исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169311/7129209